# Mongodb Domain model

Tags: c#, mongodb

just starting out on mongodb, got a question about best way to load in a domain

Here are my domain models

```
    public class TeamModel
    {
       public string TeamId {get;set;}
       public string TeamName {get;set;}
       public IEnumerable<PlayerModel> Players {get; set; }
    }

    public class PlayerModel
    {
       public string PlayerId {get; set;}
       public string TeamId {get; set; }
       public string PlayerName {get; set;}
    }
```

Now here are my MongoDb Entities

```
    public class Team
    {
       public string TeamId {get; set;}
       public string TeamName {get;set;}
    }

    public class Player
    {
       public string PlayerId {get; set;}
       public string TeamId {get; set; }
       public string PlayerName {get; set;}
    }
```

Now I dont want to have Player as an embedded document on team because not only can Players move teams often, but there are other querys that go against the Player Collection. What would be the best efficent way to load in the Domain models? Or would it involve two querys, one to get a team and then one query to get each player for that team?

Comment: Like don't use mongodb? This is absolutely trivial within any RDBMS and you have clearly typical relational structure.

Comment: Hi Andrey, I'm building a highly data driven web application with big storage, as far as I know mongodb which perform much faster and at lower costs, hence my choice for mongodb

Comment: @Luke Don't believe the hype ;)

Comment: Yeah I am wondering how people were building "highly data driven web applications" for years before mongo appeared. Sounds a little bit like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2F-DItXtZs

Comment: @ikkuh Not one for being a sheep, but my own experience, since I now have SQL and MongoDB on my azure account, mongodb is not only working out cheaper, but performs faster with my dummy data, pretty hard to ignore that, but I'm happy to read any other article to stop me from switching fully to mongo

Comment: @Andrey, I'm not a millionaire, so mongodb cheaper costs are attractive for me, happy to be proven otherwise though as I would prefer to stick with sql as its what Im used to

Comment: @Luke Data is not just data, by that your environment also takes a big part is this kinda disicions. Within a cloud you are almost forced to go for NoSQL becuase cloud sucks at diskIO (hence the hype). Yeas Mongo can be much much faster if your dataset complies to mongo/NoSQL its requirements. But just using mongo becuase it is NoSQL is going to give you alot of problems believe me, I've seen loads and loads of projects end up paying larges sums of money to get their crappy NoSQL app working in the cloud.. while there is no need for them... will your dataset be bigger than 100gb?

Comment: I cant imagine the database will be larger then 100gb, im probably looking at around 60gb, is the performance only good at past that? I would much rather stick with sql as it makes modelling my domain easier, but I do want my app in the cloud and costs will be a big issue for me, if the difference in cost will be little, then sticking with sql will be my preference